# Cells evaluated by user-defined module do not update automatically

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I read the questions existing but no answer seemed to help. I have a function I wrote in VB which evaluates sum of cells in a certain range by font color, it all works well when I type the function in (the evaluation is correct).

But when I change one cell's (a cell which is in the function's range) color, the sum value does not change at all. It only changes (in that certain cell) when I re-enter the function (I don't have to completely erase, I just have to press enter again when marking the function).

What could the problem be? All of the settings seem okay and I've tried opening a new worksheet but the problem insists.

Note:

Ctrl + Alt + F9 works, but `Application.Volatile` doesn't (although I'm in Excel 2013).

Here's my code anyway (although it's working):

```
Public Function SumByColor(rng As Range, clr As String) As Double
Application.Volatile

Dim s As Double
s = 0
Dim r As Range
Dim c As Long
If clr = "red" Then
    c = RGB(256, 0, 0)
End If
If clr = "black" Then
    c = RGB(0, 0, 0)
End If

For Each r In rng
    If r.Font.Color = c Then
        s = s + r.Value
    End If
Next r

SumByColor = s
End Function
```

Comment: **Help us to help you: post your current code.**

Comment: @Gary'sStudent No reason to add it, really. But done.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.Volatile` is not enough.........the function will calculate every time the worksheet is calculates and that may not happen if you just change colors.

**EDIT#1:**

First we make a one line change to your *UDF()* to make it accept an optional variant argument that it does not use!:

```
Public Function SumByColor(rng As Range, clr As String, Optional v As Variant) As Double
   Application.Volatile
   Dim s As Double
   s = 0
   Dim r As Range
   Dim c As Long

   If clr = "red" Then
       c = RGB(256, 0, 0)
   End If
   If clr = "black" Then
       c = RGB(0, 0, 0)
   End If

   For Each r In rng
       If r.Font.Color = c Then
           s = s + r.Value
       End If
   Next r

   SumByColor = s
End Function
```

and then in the worksheet, use something like:

```
=SumByColor(A1:A14,"red",NOW())
```

[image]

The idea is that if you touch <kbd>**F9**</kbd>, `NOW()` will be re-calculated and so will the *UDF()* .

Comment: Then what is? Is there an event I can overwrite which is fired when changing the color of a cell?

Comment: @ZachP  We can *improve* this issue.....check back later today!

Comment: @ZachP  See my **EDIT#1**

Comment: It does ease the use a bit (F9 instead of the combination of it with ctrl + alt) but it still doesn't update automatically. Is there no way to do so?